# Detecting noise in a dictionary of topic words

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, classification

I have a dictionary of about 1500 words. Not all of those 1500 words can be used as topics for text (many of them are noise in my dictionary, perhaps only 2-10% of them can be used as topics), but the topics I want to give to my documents can be found among those 1500 words.

Therefore where should I start and what algorithm may work? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try tf-idf? And are your topic key-words with high-score as result?

Comment: Questions: a) Where does the noise come from? b) What do you mean by "topic"? (how do you want to use these topics?)

Comment: a) The noise come from people used to label their documents, but sometimes they use them as emotion feeling or state which type of content they are talking; b) I want to use these topics if people can agree this a document mainly talk about these topics, it could be an event, a people in this event or something else

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of times each topic assigned by people appeared in those documents. To account for morphological variations of words, you could use a stemmer or lemmatiser (e.g., the Stanford PoS tagger for Java or NLTK for Python). Then you can select most useful topics based simply of their count in the entire set of documents, or use tf-idf (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf - at the bottom of the page there are links to some implementations).